# iterating over the columns of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot some histograms of the values in the columns of a dataframe in pandas and I want to loop over the columns for a compact code but the code keeps throwing an error?

```
for c in df.columns:
    axes[i,0].hist(df[df.num>0].c.tolist())
    i +=1
```

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'c'
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Surely you've encountered an error before, right? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

Chain column can not use in the for loop

```
axes[i,0].hist(df.loc[df.num>0,c].tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dot notation with variables. I think what you want to go for is

```
for c in df.columns:
    axes[i,0].hist(df[df.num>0][c].tolist())
    i +=1
```